# Python, ssh and multithreading : threads can only be started once

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, ssh

I'm using Python and Netmiko to crawl through my network infrastructure via ssh connections. Unfortunately, the code will not be executable unless you have a similar network infrastructure of your own.

My question is more on the multithreading theory in python.

Here is the algorithm of what I want to achieve:

connect to my core switch. 
Gather neighbors information.
Disconnect

Put neighbors in a list.
Browsing the list:
connect to each neighbor
Gather neighbors information.
Disconnect
Put new neighbors in the same list.

Here is the main problematic loop:

```
#ssh to all equipements in neighbors detecteid, gather info+ update neighbors list. Multithread to be much faster
    #cannot be more than 6 waves of uplink
    for i in range(6):
        #browse switch name in the list
        for a_device in switch_list[3::3]:
            #if the neighbor was not already analyzed
            if not switch_list[switch_list.index(a_device)+2]:
                    print('connection to...' + a_device)
                    #multithread all neighbors to be analyzed and update list
                    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=ssh_and_gather, args=(a_device,location,switch_list)))

        for x in threads:
            x.start()

        for x in threads:
            x.join()
```

It fails with the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ansible_switch_discover.py", line 130, in <module>
    main()
   File "ansible_switch_discover.py", line 114, in main
    x.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 741, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
```

How could I fix my code so it continues to add threads (ssh connections to newly discovered neighbors) to the multithreading ?

I tried to start() only once, but the error is then:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ansible_switch_discover.py", line 132, in <module>
    main()
  File "ansible_switch_discover.py", line 119, in main
    x.join()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 940, in join
    raise RuntimeError("cannot join thread before it is started")
```

thanks

Comment: You are appending the same thread multiple times to the same list so in the for loop where you start the thread you got this error: **threads can only be started once**.

For the second error probably you are trying to join a thread that is not started.

Comment: Some day, when you have some spare time, you should sit down and learn about _[Test Driven Development](https://www.amazon.com/Growing-Object-Oriented-Software-Guided-Tests/dp/0321503627)_. I know there's been a lot of hype surrounding the subject, and a lot of misunderstanding; but if you do it right, then it'll be a rare day when you have to tell somebody, "Unfortunately, the code will not be executable unless you [_can replicate my environment_]" because most of your code will be executable in your _test harness_, which you will be able to execute most anywhere.

Comment: thanks for your insights guys. As my company does not want to spend any time or money I'm working on this "rogue" so my time is limited.

I think I fixed my issue by adding threads = [] at the beginning of the for loop, and still storing on going threads in a dict:

allthreads[i] = threads

Comment: Yeah, it is a solution. But also check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Note to understand my language:

**range loop**: `for i in range(6):`

**start loop**:

```
for x in threads:
            x.start()
```

**join loop**:

```
for x in threads:
            x.join()
```

---

The problem is that you are trying to start the same thread multiples times:

```
for i in range(6):
    for a_device in switch_list[3::3]:
        if not switch_list[switch_list.index(a_device)+2]:
                print('connection to...' + a_device)
                threads.append(threading.Thread(target=ssh_and_gather, args=(a_device,location,switch_list)))

    for x in threads:
        x.start()

    for x in threads:
        x.join()
```

The list **threads** contains multiple threads (that are the same thread), and this is what you need, but is not the correct way.

The position of the start and join loop is not correct, you can solve placing it like this (outside of the range loop):

```
threads = list()
for i in range(6):
    for a_device in switch_list[3::3]:
        if not switch_list[switch_list.index(a_device)+2]:
                print('connection to...' + a_device)
                threads.append(threading.Thread(target=ssh_and_gather, args=(a_device,location,switch_list)))

for x in threads:
    x.start()

for x in threads:
    x.join()
```

Now in this code, as first thing you create all the threads, after that start and join it, so you don't get any error, because you are not starting the same thread multiple times.

The other way to do this would be to keep you code, and after the start and join loop, clear the threads list, so the thread is started only one time.

---

**TRY TO EXPLAIN:**

This is the threads list after the first range loop:

```
threads = [th1, th2, th3, th4, th5, th6]
```

now all of this threads are started and joined according to your code.
In the second loop you append more threads to the list:

```
threads = [th1, th2, th3, th4, th5, th6, th1, th2, th3, th4, th5, th6]
```

Now you start and join again the threads, but, you start the th1 in the position 0 of the list, when you reach the th1 in the position 6 of the list, it raise the error, because is the same object of the th1 (so you are starting the same thread multiple times).

So, to solve the problem, you can keep the start and join list in your code position and add the thread remove after starting and joining it, or you can move out of the range loop the start and join loop.